# Jrebel eclipse tomcat republish problem

Tags: jrebel

when using jrebel, How can I  make it automaticly republish static resource such as HTML javascript and jsp?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use rebel.xml configuration file to map your resources like jsps to the deployed app.

Check out the example: http://www.zeroturnaround.com/reference-manual/app.html#app-3.1

Comment: link doesn't work :-/